Would having a review article published in a reputable journal as sole author look good to grad programs?
I'm aiming for a PhD in computational neuroscience or cognitive neuroscience (if it turns out I'm no better at applied mathematics by the time I finish undergrad).
I have been doing experimental psychology research on novelty and reward processing in those suffering from common psychiatric symptoms. I started this research several months ago under the supervision of a professor of psychology.
I have a relatively advanced understanding of my field (I was a very bored and curious teen/pre-teen) and wanted to dedicate my undergrad to building foundational research experience rather than learning material I'm already familiar with. I can pass a psychology GRE exam and can pass most schools cumulative bachelor's exams (or senior exams) in behavioral neuro/neuroscience no issue, so I wanted to have a solid research background to prepare me for my PhD.
As big-headed as I was, I did not anticipate how difficult conducting research was, mostly how difficult it was to gather enough data and work around flakey participants, not to mention how difficult it was to model the experimental data. I graduate here in summer of 2025  and start my neuro degree in fall of 2025.
I was aiming to have a publication with my supervisor by the time I graduate, but it may fall through at this rate. I wrote up a review article and submitted to a reputable neuroscience journal that covers my specific topics often, it's currently undergoing peer review. I wanted to do research at my next institution under the supervision of a faculty member, possibly get my name on a publication or two (maybe even as primary author if I can convince a faculty member to let me work on a project of my own interest). I feel like having a publication in a reputable journal will help me make a convincing case for a faculty member when I write up a research proposal, I'm just wondering if it will make me a more appealing candidate when I apply  for a PhD.
I am also wondering if it will be useful to write two or three other review articles before I finish my undergrad. Ideally I'd have my name on original experimental research, but  fat chance a faculty member at an established research/medical school  will take me seriously if I ask to work on a project that interests me.
EDIT: I appreciate all of the advice, and have taken all of your advice to heart. I'll extend more effort to actually gaining research experience rather than trying to find an easy way out as a means to to fluff my CV. I appreciate  the grounded perspectives.

Instead of considering writing an article because it helps you (or not), consider who the intended audience of your article is, and why would they want to read what you write? Take into account that there are already way too many articles published.

I recognize that different fields have different review article cultures, but I have a hard time imagining an undergraduate who hasn't published original work yet could produce three useful review articles.

@Anyon that's completely fair, I have experience in whole brain network modeling and some experience tinkering with ANN's.  I am currently doing supervised research and will be using computational methods for my data analysis. As for how i could, I know it seems rather conceited, but i have a solid/advanced  conceptual understanding (and a moderate/ basic techinical one). I wasn't exaggerating when i said i spent a good portion of my teen years immersing myself in this, by age 16 i could keep up in academic conversations. That said, your criticism is fair and i often get ahead of myself.

@MaartenBuis Thats fair, I just want to secure my position in  a good PhD program, and people tend to take the idea of undergrads doing scholarly research as insulting/ laughable. I was lucky my supervisor now wasn't one of those people. I'll keep this in mind, and i'll make sure that I actually consider the weight of my percieved contributions before i pull a lit review out my rear end  just to make my CV a bit more appealing. I appreciate the grounded perspective.

@Anyon: different fields have different review article cultures --- This is definitely something I had no idea about until I began reading Academia SE about 8 years ago. In mathematics, survey/review papers are nearly always written by a seasoned researcher who is especially knowledgeable with recognized expertise in a certain topic, and only rarely would be attempted by a recent Ph.D. Example 1 and Example 2 and Example 3

@diddyDANK Welcome to Ac.SE. Not to burst your bubble, but anyone who is thinking about a PhD in X has a "relatively advanced understanding" of their field, and should easily pass a subject GRE. I left that para in, but I don't think it's really necessary. The US doesn't have bachelor's exams, so I can't comment on that, but I would suspect anyone who is only six months out from graduating should be able to pass one ...

Can you clarify "I graduate here in summer of 2025 and start my neuro degree in fall of 2025." Is the latter a master's degree?

I made some other light edits (to "get your name on a publication" means to be a "co-author").

@DaveLRenfro In my fields (not too far from diddy), grad students are often encouraged to try to  publish their qualifying paper as a review paper. I didn't, but there's definitely a cultural notion.

@AzorAhai-him-i haven't started my neuro degree and am finishing my associates in comp sci, my neuro degree will be an undergrad degree. And i'm not too sure about that, The school i'm attending for my neuro degree requires seniors to pass a cumulative exam and requires honors students to complete independent research before graduation.

@diddyDANK You still have a lot of time, then, to have a research publication.

@DaveLRenfro That's true for OP's field (which I am in), too, at least as far as useful reviews that other people will read and use. Recent PhDs may find that the background part of their thesis is easily translatable to a review and those might be useful, too, depending on their area of research. But, as Azor Ahai mentions, that doesn't mean that undergraduates and new grad students aren't encouraged to try to publish these things by their mentors.

At top programs in your fields of interest in the US, you will be competing with applicants who do have research papers. Whether that should be "required" or not isn't really the point: when admissions is competitive, you're competing. Undergrads I've worked with who applied to graduate school had difficulty without a publication and then success in subsequent cycles with publication.
I don't think there is much value at all in most "review papers" published by undergraduates, though. They look to me like just CV padding. I think it's fine if you have one review paper, but I wouldn't try to stack a bunch of them, it's not going to make up for a lack of research papers. You'll have trouble getting them published in actually reputable journals, because there just isn't any value in these papers. Some publishers will accept them for a hefty open-access fee.
Then again, the humans reading your applications might be fooled and see a bunch of "papers" as evidence of productivity, so I can't say for sure that it won't help. But, I would put your focus instead on getting a research publication and figuring out what you need to do to get it, which might include securing a job to finish that work before starting graduate school (definitely apply in the meantime, though).
If you have a paper that is complete and ready to be submitted but unlikely to be accepted by the time your applications are due, I would highly recommend talking to your coauthors about posting it as a preprint: a preprint isn't quite the same as an accepted peer-reviewed publication, but it means a ton more than a vague claim that some CV item is "in preparation" or "submitted". It would be a lot more meaningful than a review.

This is good advice. When I sit on grad admissions committees I am well aware of the fact that undergraduates often have very little control on publication times for lab-based research. A preprint is a great idea, and additionally, if the faculty writing the letter of support can mention potential manuscripts that will be coming out, that is usually more than good enough. If I see too many CV padding fluff papers, that is a bit of a red flag. Will this person really want to do quality research, or will their PhD just be more CV padding towards their postdoc? i.e. is this systematic behavior?

@R1NaNo There's also just very little connection between "capable of writing an undergrad-level review" and "interested enough in research to follow through when stuff is tough"; as OP notes, it's easy to underestimate how difficult research is when all you know of it is reading the papers that result.

Yes, anything you publish in a reputable journal will help you. It is a positive. But whether it is enough or not depends on too many factors to assume you will be successful in gaining admission to a "top level" institution. In many fields (this is not mine) the programs at such institutions are small and have a huge number of highly qualified applicants. You need to be competitive in many areas, not just publications.
My advice is to do what you can in research and publications, but when it comes time to apply for graduate study, cast a wide net. If your self assessment is accurate then I'd guess you have a good chance, but those evaluating your record (and the records of others) will make decisions.
I can almost guarantee that if you apply to ONLY the top three institutions in the world you won't get accepted. (almost)
In the US alone, in many fields, there are at least fifty (at least) institutions in which you  can get a fine education. There will be professors qualified at all of them. Not every top-level professor is at a top-level institution, for somewhat the same reasons as above (small size) but also personal preference about where and how to live.
See the following for admissions guidance in many countries: How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?. Note, importantly, that no single thing works anywhere unless you are truly exceptional.

thank you, and I don't plan on applying to just the top programs, just want a program with enough funding and resources to allow me to carry out the research that interests me.
